# Stop scrolling at a certain point and continue to use scroll-movement to do stuff

Tags: javascript, scroll, parallax

I searched now for a couple of hours and didn´t find a idea of how could I achieve the following:

I have a website (with teasers, images, text, etc.). At some scroll-point, there should be a special section (changing content for example) - if I reach that section - the normal scroll behaviour should stop and switches the content after a predefined scroll-distance (for example the window-height). After reaching the "end" of the third content, the normal scrolling should continue.

I hope this description makes it clear what I mean.

Thanks in advance for any tipps and hints! :)

**EDIT:**

I created an example that works almost and shows better what I mean:

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>scroll-test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="frame">
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section class="section__tabs"></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
            <section></section>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

```
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: none;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    .frame {
      position: relative;
    }
    
    section {
      height: 75vh;
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }
    section:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #aaa;
    }
    section.section__tabs {
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #000;
      position: relative;
    }
    section.section__tabs.element1 {
      background: red;
    }
    section.section__tabs.element1.element2, section.section__tabs.element2 {
      background: orange;
    }
    section.section__tabs.sticky {
      position: -webkit-sticky;
      position: sticky;
    }
    section.section__tabs.sticky--down {
      top: 0;
    }
    section.section__tabs.sticky--up {
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```
    $(function () {
      // the elements position
      var stickyTop = $('.section__tabs').offset().top; 
      // the elements height
      var sectionHeight = $('.section__tabs').height();
      var scrollFactor1 = 1.5;
      var scrollFactor2 = 2;
      var scrollFinishedDown = false;
      var scrollFinishedUp = false;
      var previousScroll = 0;
      $(window).scroll(function () {
        var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop(); 
       // If scrolled down
    
        if (windowTop > previousScroll) {
          // If the scroll-position reached the sticky element and is not finished scrolling through the elements
          if (windowTop > stickyTop && windowTop < stickyTop + sectionHeight * scrollFactor2 && !scrollFinishedDown) {
            // Set the element sticky
            $('.section__tabs').addClass('sticky sticky--down'); // activate the second element
    
            if (windowTop > stickyTop + sectionHeight) {
              $('.section__tabs').addClass('element1');
            } // activate the third element
    
    
            if (windowTop > stickyTop + sectionHeight * scrollFactor1) {
              $('.section__tabs').addClass('element2');
            } // after the third element
    
    
            if (windowTop > stickyTop + sectionHeight * scrollFactor2) {
              // remove the sticky class
              $('.section__tabs').removeClass('sticky sticky--down'); // set the correct scroll distance
    
              $(window).scrollTop(stickyTop); // done for now
    
              scrollFinishedDown = true;
            }
          } else {
            // Remove the sticky classes
            $('.section__tabs').removeClass('sticky sticky--down'); // lets start again
    
            scrollFinishedDown = false;
          } // If scrolled up
    
        } else {
          // If we pass the elements top
          if (windowTop < stickyTop && !scrollFinishedUp) {
            // Set the sticky class
            $('.section__tabs').addClass('sticky sticky--up'); // after the third element remove class
    
            if (windowTop < stickyTop - sectionHeight) {
              $('.section__tabs').removeClass('element2');
            } // after second element remove class
    
    
            if (windowTop < stickyTop - sectionHeight * scrollFactor1) {
              $('.section__tabs').removeClass('element1');
            } // after first element
    
    
            if (windowTop < stickyTop - sectionHeight * scrollFactor2) {
              // remove class
              $('.section__tabs').removeClass('sticky sticky--up'); // done for now
    
              scrollFinishedUp = true;
            }
          } else {
            // Remove the sticky classes
            $('.section__tabs').removeClass('sticky sticky--up'); // letÂ´s start again
    
            scrollFinishedUp = false;
          }
        } // remember the scroll position
    
    
        previousScroll = windowTop;
      });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/L0dkpw1u/

Here is just one Problem: After scrolling through the "special element" it jumps directly to far down or up. How can I achieve, that it scrolls away, like the normal behaviour would be?

**AND:** Any suggestions or better ways to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You need to show us your code and effort in solving it. Nobody will type code from scratch for you.

Comment: @ozgur - thank you for your comment. I don't want to have a final solution. I just need an idea where to start. The biggest problem that I have at the moment is to figure out how to stop the scrolling and use it to do something else...